# Error form dropdown database codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I need help in my code:A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

p>Message:  Use of undefined constant album - assumed 'album'

Filename: painel/aquiler.php

Line Number: 26

My Model:

```
public function get_inquilinos(){
    $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $this->db->where('id_inqueilino_refe_usu', $id);
    $this->db->like('tipo_usu', 'inquilino');
    $query  = $this->db->get('usuarios');
    if ($query-> num_rows ()> 0) {
        foreach ($query-> result_array () as $row) {
            $data [] = $row;
            }
    }
    $query-> free_result ();
    return $data;
}
```

My View:

```
  $data['album'] = $this->sindico->get_inquilinos();
echo "<select name='id' id='id'>";
if (count($album)) {
foreach ($album as $list) {
echo "<option value='". $list['id_usu'] . "'>" . $list['nome_usu'] . "</option>";
}
}
echo "</select><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have listed down here, the error seems to be correct.

You have

```
$data['album'] = $this->sindico->get_inquilinos();
```

Then you have used  `(count($album)` without assigning any values to $album.

Either you need to use `count($data['album'])` or assign like
`$album = $data['album']` and then use `count($album)`

Answer (score 0):

please use this way --

```
$album = $this->sindico->get_inquilinos();
echo "<select name='id' id='id'>";
if (count($album)) {
foreach ($album as $list) {
echo "<option value='". $list['id_usu'] . "'>" . $list['nome_usu'] . "</option>";
}
}
echo "</select><br/>";
```

you can use directly **$album** into view file but we you will use this model method into controller then you have to use **$data['album']**